# Django AssertionError: Expected a `Response` `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse to be returned from the view but received a <class NoneType>

Tags: python, django

I don't understand whats going on with my code since i'm getting the same error when i try to do a POST

MODELS

```
from django.db import models

class License(models.Model):

    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    user_full_name= models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True,blank=False)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False)
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True, blank=False)
    software_user_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False)
    expiration_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_full_name + ' ' + self.job_title + ', user: ' + self.software_user_name
```

SERIALIZER

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import License


class LicenseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta():
        model = License
        fields = ['id', 'company_name', 'user_full_name', 'job_title', 'user_email',     'software_user_name', 'expiration_date', 'version']
```

VIEWS

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import License
from .serializers import LicenseSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def license_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
    
         licenses = License.objects.all()
         serializer = LicenseSerializer(licenses, many=True)
         return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = LicenseSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

URLS

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from licenseapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('licenses/', views.license_list)
]
```

I want to understand what's going on and find a solution because it seems to me everything is ok

Entire Error

Internal Server Error: /licenses/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kira5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kira5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kira5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kira5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kira5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 511, in dispatch    self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kira5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 423, in finalize_response
assert isinstance(response, HttpResponseBase), (
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
[06/Jul/2023 21:45:33] "POST /licenses/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the `serializer.errors` with **`Response`**

#### -------- views.py ----------

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def license_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':    
        licenses = License.objects.all()
        serializer = LicenseSerializer(licenses, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = LicenseSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)    
        else:    
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises in this code block

```py
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = LicenseSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Here `serializer.is_valid()` if this is not True then there is nothing to return (ie. `<class 'NoneType'>`). So you have to give a `else` there, as follows-

```py
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)    
        else:    
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```